# Modify fopen in C

Tags: c

Please i'd like to modify:

```
f = fopen("/home/file.txt", "w");
```

Th have the result of:

```
f = fopen("/home/%s.txt", "w",argv[1]);
```

Have you an idea about an option in fopen ?

Thank you.

Comment: What is the third argument? What did you try?

Comment: [What Have You Tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com), what's the purpose having that third argument?

Comment: I don't see why this is so hard to do. A bit of algorithmical thinking would have easily revealed the solution. Please think before you ask next time.

Comment: @H2CO3 Yes, it's a very basic question, but it may be hard to grasp the C way of doing things for novices (especially without knowing which `sprintf/snprintf/vsnprintf/...` is)

Comment: @Kiril Kirov: i'd like to pass the name of the file as parameter: for exp i do ./prog Myfile --> a file with name (Myfile.txt) will be created

Comment: @EarlGray I'm wondering why I haven't needed to ask such questions in this case. I understand what your problem is, but I still do not agree with you entirely.

Comment: @H2CO3: because y're not novice simply

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd suggest this:

```
char filename[MAX_PATH];
snprintf(filename, sizeof(filename), "/home/%s.txt", argv[1]);
f = fopen(filename, "w");
```

Modifying the `fopen` is not a trivial task, though you can write a wrapper with the operations above.

Comment: EarlGrey: instead of passing it the buffer size, pass `sizeof(buffer)`, that's more secure.

Comment: @H2CO3 What if one chooses to dynamically allocate filename and free it post open?

Answer (score 3):

Simply wrap the `fopen` call in a function:

```
FILE* my_fopen(char filename[]) {
    static char buffer[MAXIMUM_SIZE];
    snprintf(buffer, MAXIMUM_SIZE, "/home/%s.txt", filename);
    return fopen(buffer, "w");
}
```

Then all you have to do is call `my_fopen("myfile.txt")`.

Comment: `FILE* my_fopen(char* filename, char* path, char* mode) {
    static char buffer[MAXIMUM_SIZE];
    snprintf(buffer, MAXIMUM_SIZE, "%s/%s", path,filename);
    return fopen(buffer, mode);
}`

Answer (score 0):

`fopen()` doesn't take a format string, so you have to construct it beforehand:

```
char buf[MAX_PATH];
snprintf(buf, sizeof(buf), "/home/%s.txt", argv[1]);
FILE *f = fopen(buf, "w");
```